# What is more common "table booking" or "table reservation"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

What is more common and natural, "table booking" or "table reservation"?

Is there a big difference between these two?

Comment: "table booking" sure sounds very funny.. :P Just imagine someone booking for you on a table like a movie ticket being booked at a counter(in contrast to online booking, telephone booking etc.) BTW, where did you get this?

Comment: It came from "book a table". It looks that "table booking" is invalid :)

Comment: Yes, "table booking" is not correct, at least not for me.

Comment: Maybe it's regional.  I'm from Lincolnshire, England, and a "table booking" is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Only *reservation* seems fine. The context is obvious, I think, and need not be specified.

Comment: I worked in the catering business in England and Ireland and I've heard "table booking" often, for example:  http://booknow.tgifridays.co.uk/  or  http://www.guestlistspot.com/tables/booking-enquiry

Answer (score 1):

On the subject of restaurants, one talks of wanting to book a table, or to make a reservation.  When arriving at the restaurant, the form is 'We have a booking (or reservation)' or 'We've booked (or reserved) a table'.

Answer (score 1):

"Table reservation" sounds more formal.